# Exception ; An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

Hello I have a windows phone 8 application I got exception

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Here are the code

```
  private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double basestolen;
        double attempedstales;
        double avarege;
        double putout;




         if (puttext.Text.Length == 0 | basetext.Text.Length==0 )
        {

            MessageBox.Show(" Enter Values for Base Stolen and Putouts ");

        }

         basestolen = Convert.ToDouble(basetext.Text);
        putout = Convert.ToDouble(puttext.Text);



        attempedstales = basestolen + putout;


        if (attempedstales != 0  )
        {

            avarege = (((basestolen / attempedstales) / 100));
            avarege = avarege * 10000;
            avgtext.Text = Convert.ToString(avarege);


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Attemped Stales Value should not be Zero");
        }



    }
```

The application run and If I don't enter a value in the textboxes it's return the msg box but after that the application stop and return the exption above ? what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The error is most likely here:

```
basestolen = Convert.ToDouble(basetext.Text);
putout = Convert.ToDouble(puttext.Text);
```

It throws a FormatException if the number is not in a valid format. ([see more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx)). Try using [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) to parse your values in a safe way.

```
double result;    
bool success = double.TryParse(basetext.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to stop the execution of your method after displaying the message box:

```
if (puttext.Text.Length == 0 || basetext.Text.Length==0 )
{
    MessageBox.Show(" Enter Values for Base Stolen and Putouts ");
    return;
}
```

Also, when converting strings into double, make sure to specify the culture. Your Windows Phone application will be executed by users all around the world, and some countries use different decimal separators. For instance:

```
basestolen = Convert.ToDouble(basetext.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```